# get stacktrace of all threads

Tags: c#

I would like to log the stack trace of all threads in my c# application (UI). I can get the stack trace of all managed threads using WinDbg with the following commands.

.loadby sos mscorwks
~* e !clrstack

Is there any other easy methods to get the callstack of all threads in my c# application? This is because I want to get the callstack when the application is running in the customer machine and the customer is not a technical person

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion try to grab a user dump of application using either Adplus+WinDbg or DebugDiag. And do a postmortem debugging using the userdump

[Here's a good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/08/23/getting-full-user-mode-dumps-automatically-when-your-process-crashes.aspx) about capturing user dumps automatically on process crashes

Good Reads 
[Tess Fernandez's blog on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/)

http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2008/10/31/beginner-guide-to-windbg-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it in a live process as well if you do deploy Windbg to the customer machine as well and then use [WMemoryProfiler](https://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/) to execute a debugger command. It sounds strange but you can actually debug yourself with a debugger automaticaly.

See [here](https://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Self%20Debugging&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
private static void SelfDebug()
{
    using (var debugger = new MdbEng())
    {
        string[] output = debugger.Execute("~*e!ClrStack");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
    }
}
```